# Is it more efficient to do DistinctBy().Select() or Select().DistinctBy()? C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code but I'm not sure which of the 2 options below would be more efficient. Could anyone let me know which is more efficient and why?

```
var list1 = await context.Data.Where(i => i.Market == "nasdaq").DistinctBy(i => i.Symbol).Select(i => i.Symbol).ToListAsync();

var list2 = await context.Data.Where(i => i.Market == "nasdaq").Select(i => i.Symbol).DistinctBy(i => i).ToListAsync();
```

Note: I use the MoreLinq Library

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Sorry I forgot to specify that I use the MoreLinq library

Comment: `DistinctBy` and MoreLinq have nothing in common with EF because they operate on `IEnumerable<T>`. The most efficient is to use `Select` + `Distinct` (no `By`) which will be translated to SQL and executed in database.

Comment: I don't think there is much difference between the two, since the two DistinctBy calls use a predicate so using it on a list of data or on a list of symbols directly is pretty much the same. If you're still curious as to which of the two is more efficient, do a simple benchmark and see for yourself, but honestly I wouldn't "waste" time on such small "optimisations"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since MoreLinq library does not provide `DistinctBy` on `IQueryable<T>`, only on `IEnumerable<T>`, the part of your first query after `Where` completes in memory. Hence, the entire object gets transferred, which is suboptimal.

The second query takes only `Symbol`, so it is slightly better. However, duplicate symbols are still transferred into memory, so there's room for optimization.

You can improve on it by observing that `DistinctBy(i => i)` is the same as `Distinct()`:

```
var list2 = await context.Data
    .Where(i => i.Market == "nasdaq")
    .Select(i => i.Symbol)
    .Distinct()
    .ToListAsync();
```

Now everything is done on the RDBMS side, including elimination of duplicates.